# How do I add a failure block objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been through a few Stack Overflow questions and I can't seem to figure how to adapt my code to include a failure block. How can I add a failure block to this code?

```
+ (void)loginUser:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password :(void (^)(BOOL finished))completionBlock {
  NSString *endpoint = @"Users/Login";
  [self postEndpoint:endpoint params:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:username, @"Username", password, @"Password", nil] completionBlock:^(DollarResponse *response) {
      NSLog(@"%@",response);
    if ([response.result isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
      [self displayError:response.message];
    } else {
      Login *login = [[Login alloc] initWithDictionary:response.result];
      [self saveLogin:login];
      completionBlock(YES);
    }
}];
     /* loginUser:withPassword:: */
```

Comment: What do you consider a failure block and why is the last parameter's name missing?

Comment: Do you mean that you want an additional parameter that represents a failure block?

Comment: BTW - please fix your code formatting.

Comment: Hope that format is a little better

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to pass your block. It is useful to define a type for that:

```
 typedef void (^MyErrorBlock)(NSString* error);
```

Note that your are going to pass an error in that block as a `NSString` because your `response.message` it seems like a string. Although usually error blocks pass an `NSError`.

To pass it as a parameter you can do:

```
 -(void)loginUser:(NSString *)username 
     withPassword:(NSString *)password 
     (void (^)(BOOL finished)): completionBlock
                  (MyErrorBlock): errorBlock
```

Then you can call it as you call your completionBlock, but you then pass `response.message` like this:

```
 errorBlock(response.message)
```

You can also save a pointer to your errorBlock and then call it when you need it.

Comment: BTW - the name of this method, as proposed, is `loginUser:withPassword:::`. I suggest giving names to the last two parameters. And this ignores the two typos where you have the colon after the parameter type instead of before the parameter type.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use a generic and simplistic completion block for asynchronous *methods* when possible and when suitable as in your case. There is no special "failure" block - since the failure case will be handled by the call-site directly in the completion block. See example below:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(id result);

-(void) loginUser:(NSString *)username 
     withPassword:(NSString *)password 
       completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;
```

(see below for a better naming of the method)

In the documentation you state:

> The result parameter returns @"OK" in case of success, otherwise a NSError object containing details about the error.

(Of course, you may return something different, and more suitable as the result in case of success)

Well, then you may use it as follows:

```
[foo loginUser:user withPassword:pass completion:^(id result){
    if (![result isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

---

There are countless other valid and reasonable signatures for a completion handler:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(NSData* data, NSError* error);
```

This one, apparently, returns a NSData in case of success, and a NSError in case of a failure. The documentation *shall* specify the details.

---

You may define different handlers (blocks) as *properties* when you have an *Operation* object which performs an *asynchronous* task (e.g., a subclass of `NSOperation`) Since your example deals with an asynchronous *method*, there's no reason to explain that here, unless you post a new question. ;)

Edit:

According the naming conventions, I would suggest the following:

```
-(void) loginWithUsername:(NSString *)username 
                 password:(NSString *)password 
               completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;
```